# UICollectionView attempts to dequeue cells beyond data source bounds while reordering is in progress

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

I have implemented collection view with cell reordering

```
class SecondViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!
    private var numbers: [[Int]] = [[], [], []]

    private var longPressGesture: UILongPressGestureRecognizer!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        for j in 0...2 {
            for i in 0...5 {
                numbers[j].append(i)
            }
        }

        longPressGesture = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "handleLongGesture:")
        self.collectionView.addGestureRecognizer(longPressGesture)
    }

    func handleLongGesture(gesture: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {

        switch(gesture.state) {

        case .Began:
            guard let selectedIndexPath = self.collectionView.indexPathForItemAtPoint(gesture.locationInView(self.collectionView)) else {
                break
            }
            collectionView.beginInteractiveMovementForItemAtIndexPath(selectedIndexPath)
        case .Changed:
            collectionView.updateInteractiveMovementTargetPosition(gesture.locationInView(gesture.view!))
        case .Ended:
            collectionView.endInteractiveMovement()
        default:
            collectionView.cancelInteractiveMovement()
        }
    }

}

extension SecondViewController: UICollectionViewDataSource {

    func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return numbers.count
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
      let number = numbers[section].count
      print("numberOfItemsInSection \(section): \(number)")

      return number
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        print("cellForItemAtIndexPath: {\(indexPath.section)-\(indexPath.item)}")
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! TextCollectionViewCell
        cell.textLabel.text = "\(numbers[indexPath.section][indexPath.item])"

        return cell
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, moveItemAtIndexPath sourceIndexPath: NSIndexPath, toIndexPath destinationIndexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        let temp = numbers[sourceIndexPath.section].removeAtIndex(sourceIndexPath.item)
        numbers[destinationIndexPath.section].insert(temp, atIndex: destinationIndexPath.item)
    }
}
```

It works fine until I try to drag an item from section 0 to section 2 (which is off screen). When I drag the item to the bottom of collection view, it slowly starts scrolling down. At some point (when it scrolls past section 1) application crashes with `fatal error: Index out of range` because it attempts to request cell at index 6 in section 1 while there are only 6 items in this section. If I try to drag an item from section 1 to section 2, everything works fine.

Here's an example project reproducing this problem (credit to [NSHint](http://nshint.io/blog/2015/07/16/uicollectionviews-now-have-easy-reordering/)):
https://github.com/deville/uicollectionview-reordering

Is this a bug in framework or am I missing something? If it is the former, what would be the workaround?

Comment: Have you tried calling collectionView.reloadData() in your case .Began or .Changed? This would hopefully re-call `numberOfItems` In section which would keep the indexPath from going out of range. Performance wise this would be a lot to call it during every stage of the touch event so try to figure out which method causes the change in the actual array and try calling `reloadData()` there.

Comment: @NSGangster tried it, unfortunately, it does not fix the problem.

Comment: Well thought it was worth a shot seeing. it. If this is built in feature of collectionView I wouldn't feel too bad doing a hack around. Like setting a wider scope boolean to true when touch events start and if that variable is true adjust the index being used in itemForIndex. Might give you unexpected behavior with cells disappearing or so during movement though but just an idea if you want to try it.

Comment: @NSGangster might be the way to go, thanks for suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

I actually ran into this issue today. Ultimately the problem was in itemAtIndexPath - I was referencing the datasource to grab some properties for my cell : thus the source of the out of bounds crash. The fix for me was to keep a reference to the currently dragging cell and in itemAtIndexPath; check the section's datasource length versus the passed NSIndexPath and if out of bounds; refer to the dragging cell's property.

Likesuchas (in Obj-C ... haven't moved to Swift yet) :

```
    NSArray* sectionData = [collectionViewData objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];

    MyObject* object;

    if (indexPath.row < [sectionData count]) {
        object = [dataObject objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    } else {
        object = draggingCell.object;
    }

    [cell configureCell:object];
```

Not sure if this is similar to your exact issue; but it was mine as everything is working as expected now. :)